# An aggregate without an aggregate root?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate, service

This is not a problem I am having in my problem domain.  It is just a thought exercise.

Say I have a simple calculator like this:

```
public class Calculator
{
     public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost) 
            {
                var target = cost;
                foreach (var denomination in currency.AvailableDenominations.OrderByDescending(a => a))
                {
                   var numberRequired = target / denomination;
                   if (numberRequired > 0)    
             {
                   yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(denomination, numberRequired);
               }
               target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
            }
    } 
}
```

As it stands there is no Entity and no Aggregate root.

I believe I have two options:

1. No aggregate root: Have the application service call the domain service directly i.e. supply a cost and receive the denominations.
2. Introduce an Aggregate Root: Create a class called `ChangeRequest` like the following:

   ```
   public class ChangeRequest
   {
       public decimal Cost {get; set;}
       public listKeyValuePair<int, int> denominations {get; set;}

      public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> AddDenominations(Calculator calculator)
      {
        //Add denominations to list here.
      }
   }
   ```

Is it normal to have an aggregate without an aggregate root?

Comment: What is according to you the aggregate (with or without root) ?

Comment: @Christophe, a domain model that only contains the Calculator class in the post.

Comment: Ask yourself what the benefits are of introducing this "aggregate root."  (fwiw I don't think you have an aggregate or an aggregate root here)

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I guess that is because denominations is a KeyValuePair rather than a domain object?

Comment: No, it's because it's not an aggregate.  Aggregates and aggregate roots fulfill a specific business function; all you have here is a class and a utility class.  Try reading https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html

Comment: @Robert Harvey, fair enough.  Perhaps I should of used an Offer Calculator and a Customer as I believe that would be an aggregate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with a quote form Evans in his DDD reference book:

> Sometimes services masquerade as model objects, appearing as objects
>   with no meaning beyond doing some operation.

Keeping this in mind, we can now look at the DDD definitions:

> AGGREGATE:  A cluster of associated objects that are treated as a unit
>   for the purpose of data changes.
>
> SERVICE: An operation offered as an interface that stands alone in the
>   model, with no encapsulated state.

`Calculator` has no data an no state.  So there is no *purpose of data change*.  Consequently, there is no aggregate.  T

The operation `CalculateDenominationsFor()` is offered as part of `Calculator`'s interface.  The class stands alone in the model and has no encapsulated state. Its sole purpose is the execution of the operation.  Consequently it's a service.

Adding a fake aggregate root, just because the service is exposed via an object seems like over-engineering.

However there's still room for improvement:  the method is not dependent of any object instance, so you could declare it as [`static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).  If all the members of that class are static, you could declare the class itself as `static`.  This has the advantage of highlighting the true nature of that class.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I confirm that you are favouring option 1? +1 for: "no purpose of data change".

Comment: @w0051977 I confirm for option 1

Comment: Thanks.  Can I ask what you think of the KeyValuePair? Should this be an object rather than a key value pair?

Comment: @w0051977 from the point of view of DDD, a KeyValuePair is already a value object.  This being said, I'd encapsulate this in an object in order to decouple the design from the actual implementation and to keep the freedom to let it evolve with more complex data if you want to.

Comment: So the keyvaluepair would be represented as an object with two members? Can you give an example of complex data? That is my last question.

Comment: @w0051977 suppose that instead of `int` you want to increase precision of your calculator and use `long` instead. Ok, that was not necessarily more complex.  But now suppose that you want to work with bigints, where each of your former int would be represented by an array of int.

Comment: One more thing - would you replace Cost with an object (to remove primitive obsession)?

Comment: @w0051977 it depends. The pair is annoying because you have to know the meaning that you give to is component to process them correctly. However for cost it might be overengineering. I would certainly consider a type alias for int. I would only consider an object if my calculator would have to be able to mix different types, or if cost could evolve in something multidimensional (e.g. cost in time and cost in space; financial cost and human resource costs, etc).

Comment: if I wanted to perform validation on the cost e.g. make sure it was greater than zero and had no more than two decimal places etc, then I guessd this would be a reason to encapsulate it in a value object?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes: if there are specific semantics behind the data, it's a candidate for a value object and a distinct type. But only factor in the type the common behavior (e.g. if cost always must be positive wherever it's used). A typical example is [money](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html)

Comment: would you introduce validation for a simple program like this? It seems like a bit of an overkill. Is it normal to put the validation inside the Domain Service?

Comment: @w0051977 it depends totally on what you want to achieve: defensive coding by verifying the assumptions? management of errors and exceptions in case of invalid service requests ? validation or feedback at UI level ? Only you can judge what's suitable for the case. The question of creating or not a distinct class is more general than your ddd question. I just gave the money example above because it's quite common pattern.

Comment: thanks.  Is there a pattern where the Domain Service can do the validation itself?

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your question to "whether it's common or not having Application Service consuming Domain Service directly?" Yes, it's common.

One live example is authenticating user in Vaughn Vernon's IDDD.
Source code is [here](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/application/IdentityApplicationService.java#L122).

The author deeply compared two implementations in the chapter of domain service of IDDD book. The first attempt is using the entities directly in Application Service without introducing Domain Service. The main problem with this is that it makes Application Service (the client of domain objects) unnecessary complicated and need it unnecessary to know the internal of the domain objects.

Long story short, using the domain service directly in application service is quite useful when serving the inquiry scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by inquiry scenario?

Comment: @w0051977 anything about asking questions to the system. e.g. your calculator or authenticate a user etc.